# How can I oversee the logistics of a sinister operation that operate under one umbrella organization?

Tags: fantasy-races, children, organizations, criminal-underworld

800,000 children are reported missing every year in the U.S., roughly 2,000 a day. The majority of these kids are abducted by a species known as the Lamia, creatures masquerading as humans who kidnap and devour children. They have been operating in the shadows for many centuries, pretending to be human in order to hide their true nature. However, they are disorganized and work independently. Recent technological developments, a modern police force, and laws designed to protect children have made it more difficult to secure their food source. Gone are the days in which humans would post pictures of missing kids on milkboxes. The opportunistic, snatch and grab battle for prey isn't going to work in the new age. Therefore, a group of Lamia have decided to come together and bring their brethren under one umbrella, securing a steady supply of food and maintaining their secrecy.

Baby farming was a European practice in Victoria-age Britain.The idea is that farming children for food would guarantee a steady supply of meat, removing the need to hunt and risk exposing themselves. Stored embryos in cryopreservation would be procured for the purposes of implantation, while sperm and egg cells would also be unknowingly taken from the population for future use. Illegal immigrants, destitute and desiring passage to the states, would be paid to serve as surrogates to serve a contractual term. Once the child is born, they would be raised to a the beginning stage of puberty, about 9 or 10 years. These products will be untraceable and unknown to the authorities, so would not be missed. At a certain point, the child will be sold to the highest bidder and then devoured.

This all sounds easy on paper but is a process that involves multiple industries going on at once, from smuggling illegals across countey borders, to room and board, to medical facilicities for housing equipment. All the while maintaining secrecy and avoiding governmental agencies. I need to figure out the logistics of such a complex operation in order to make this organization run smoothly. What would I need to make this work?

Comment: You may want to read up on "Pizza-Gate". Regardless if it is true or not, it describe something similar. Sadly, pedo and grooming rings do the same, if it is not at this scale. They could cooperate, buying up the too old, used "goods". Will try to formulate a normal answer too.

Comment: Are there even 800k babies born every year in the US?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Great Old Ones Limited, or Why does Cthulhu need a Company?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/104046/21222)

Comment: I added a couple tags and swapped out [tag:mythical-creatures] for [tag:fantasy-races].  We changed their meanings a few months ago and the latter is for those creatures with human-like intelligence.

Comment: A late note, the "censored" wikipedia article might not be helpful regarding "Pizza-Gate". You may want to check out the InfoGalactic one. Regardless of validity, it is helpful for your worldbuilding problem.

Comment: "Import/Export" businesses have long been a favorite of drug cartels/gun runners/CIA to move stuff illegally. [Barry Seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Seal) is a great example of one such businessman

Comment: Ah, I see you want to open a [Long Pig](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Long%20pig) farm. Sign here and here. That'll be $300.

Comment: As every corporation Lamias would move from well connected (in matter of information and goods) country to somewhere where the rules are much loose. Like Russia or India.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: **Extremely sadly not "much"**

Most of the stuff can be legal, with a smokescreen, alibi about their end-purpose. Charity Foundations, Research Organizations, Orphanages, ... the workers don't have to know what is going on.
The truly shady stuff can be done through existing channels. Deepweb auctions, human and child trafficking, etc.

---

**Long, gruesome, disturbing answer:**

**1) Long term planning**

You can't rush it. Setting up the framework takes time without gaining attention. They could have started sooner in small scale and only scale up as demand grew. Maybe 10-20 years.
Shell agencies and locations set up, as well as the below mentioned points taken care of.

**2) Key positions influenced**

You need to have certain positions under control.

These are Big Media Corps. Don't bother with single agencies, have the MegaCorp behind them in your grasp. They will dismiss any accusations, disturbing facts which came out as conspiracy theory by lunatics.
Sociel Media - an automatic search engine (tweaked by an insider) which shadowbans, memory hole any mention, reference to your operations.

Leaders in government Agencies, who have authority on investigations. They can approve or dismiss it, allocate only minimal resources, deprioritize it and assign investigators to lead them who are incompetent or already compromised.

Politicians influenced, so they won't call for investigations and create laws which are detrimental to your plans.

**How do you do this?**
Money. Entrapment. Throw parties, where underage kids are offered. Film it. For real life example, the current Epstein case.

**3) Personnel and Logistic**

A few thoughts. Set up a shell foundations, which handles money. They will support charity and "research" into certain children related illnesses and problems. All the spending of medical stuff justified and looks good outside.

You don't need all the personnal to know everything. You can make a smokescreen, people won't look deep if they think they are heroes saving the world, like workers of the above foundation.

Only use/promote compromised people at critical positions and interconnect them. One is the others wife, lover, ... family and friendships.

Use existing infrastructure: Human, sex and child trafficking already exist.... take part in it and scale up. They don't need to know all the details.

**4) Location**

Buy an island. Set up other locations to take the fall in case of leaks or redirect the attention there. They will be "only" pedo or sex "farms".

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to understand two things to be successful.
(1)  Linear Programming
   This is a branch of mathematics created just before WW2 and was treated as TOP SECRET.  It enabled the US Armed Forces to deliver sufficient warfighting materiel -- munitions, vehicles, medical supplies, tents, socks -- to each of the combat theaters we were engaged in or were supporting.  The same mathematics is used by oil companies and telephony to calculate optimum investments in infrastructure that yield maximum return.  It's a very powerful tool.

(2) Electronic Resource Planning
    This is a modern tool of the Chief Executive.  It provides real-time information on the critical elements of a modern business engaged in manufacturing and stuff like that. It enables oversight of how raw materials and finished goods are moving through the businesses supply chain.  This tool enables both predictions of outcomes and identification of bottlenecks threatening business goals.

LP provides details on optimum planning and ERP provides the means to monitor, and identify problems needing resolution, in real-time.